# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes, laravel-blade

The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
I tried to do every solutions but it still same problem
**web.php**

```
<?php


Route::resource('tasks','TasksController');
```

**View tasks/create**

```
<form action="{{route('tasks.store') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                    @csrf
                    <!-- Task Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="task-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Task</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="task-name" class="form-control" value="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Add Task Button -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus"></i>Add Task
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**Controller TasksController**

```
  public function index()
        {

            $tasks=Task::all();
            return view('tasks.index',compact('tasks'));
        }

        public function create()
        {
            //
            return view('tasks.create');
        }

        public function store(Request $request)
        {

            $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required|max:20'
            ]);
            //Create Tasks
            $task=new Task;
            $task->name=$request->input('name');
            $task->save();
            return redirect('/tasks')->with('success','Task Created');
        }
```

Help me i don't know what is a problem
    Thank you

Comment: because you didn't naming routes

Comment: how i can name route

Comment: User php artisan:route list and see if that route already has a name, Route::resource usually creates names for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this to `web.php`

```
Route::resource('tasks','TasksController')->names([
    'store' => 'tasks.store'
]);
```

or add this

```
Route::post('/tasks/store', 'TasksController@store')->name('tasks.store');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks,but still not working

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: check my updated code

Comment: you can see my view tell is true or false

Comment: is this fixed your problem?

Comment: now i gettiing this error when i updated your new code **Class 'App\Task' not found**

Comment: i have werror when i click your chat  user 1232134

Comment: how i can chatting iwth you

Comment: Import your model top of the controller

`use App\Task`

Comment: thhank you it's working now *_*